# Использования ref на родительские элементы, в динамическом блоке React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

можете пожалуйста показать как правильно сделать ref на родительские блоки, тем более в динамических блоках

Я просто знаю, что использование селекторов в virtualDom неправильно, и нужно использовать ref

Подскажите как селекторы переделать на ref в методах addTag и editTags?
а то нигде не нахожу примера похожего с мою задачу

```js
class Home extends Component {

    editTags = (e) => {
        e.target.closest('.card-list__item--tags').classList.add('active');
    }

    addTag = (e) => {
        let tagFieldValue = e.target.closest('.card-list__item_edit').querySelector('input');
        let indexItem = e.target.closest('.card-list__item').id;
        let cardList = this.props.cards;
        cardList[indexItem].tags = cardList[indexItem].tags + ', ' + tagFieldValue.value;
        this.props.onEditTags(cardList);
        tagFieldValue.value = '';
        e.target.closest('.card-list__item--tags').classList.remove('active');
    }




    render(){
        let cardList = this.props.cards;

        return(
            <div className={'card-list'}>
                {
                    cardList.length && cardList.map((card, index) =>
                        <div id={index} className={'card-list__item'}>
                            <div className={'card-list__item_row card-list__item--tags'}>
                                <div className={'tags-wrap'} onDoubleClick={this.editTags}>
                                    {
                                        card.tags.split(', ').map((tag) =>
                                            <span>{tag}</span>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div className={'card-list__item_edit'}>
                                    <input id={index} type="text" placeholder={'Add tags'}/>
                                    <button onClick={this.addTag}>Add Tag</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;
```